# input type time is a string or datetime?

Tags: c#, html

I'm working on Angular (front-end) with C# (back-end) project going, and I'm going to use the input time `<input type="time">`

So, is the value a string, or should I save it as DateTime and get the time part only?

How should the property be on the backend and database?

```
public DateTime? Property { get; set; }
```

Or

```
public string Property { get; set; }
```

Comment: It's up to you. if you want to save the `input type="time"` element value as `DateTime`, you need to use `DateTime` on the server side.  if you want to save the time as a string, you can use string property. If you need to perform date and time calculations on the server-side, its better tp go with `DateTime?`

Comment: In both cases, is it possible to use it back to populate again using the value property? @SachithWickramaarachchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save to Database in DateTime, do all business logic in DateTime, but when you want to display to view, it is smooth to convert to string. Bellow is a sample code that i use to help with this.

```
 public string DateTimeToString(DateTime dateTime)
{
  var stringDate = dateTime.ToString("dddd, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
  return stringDate;
}
```

You can format it however you wish, this will help to keep your DateTime on tables to look uniform, and removes the need to always convert to string at the presentation layer.